# reportviewer not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ssrs-2008

I am rendering ssrs report on button click event and also downloading pdf document which contains expenses receipts.

Requirement is to show report on screen and download pdf.

If i use the following code then reportviewer doesn't render report but i can download pdf.

```
 content = myMemoryStream.ToArray();

  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "hello" + ".pdf");
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  Response.Write(content);
```

I have tried rendering reporting after response.write but no luck. Also Response.End didn't make a difference either.